# How do I run a Sinatra app as a deamon from the command line?

Tags: sinatra, thin

How do I run a Sinatra app as a deamon from the command line?

It is using Thin:

```
ruby app.rb -p 3000 -e production
```

I don't like to set it up in the app.rb itself. I want to deamonise it from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

From *[Start Sinatra app in the background with stdout and stderr redirected (append) to a file](https://serverfault.com/questions/214184/start-sinatra-app-in-the-background-with-stdout-and-stderr-redirected-append-t/214186#214186)*:

```
nohup ruby app.rb -p 3000 -e production >> log/log_file 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's possible with Ruby. But it's an easy task with `rackup`.

Just add a config.ru:

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

And with this in place you can start it as a daemon:

```
rackup -p 3000 -E production -D
```

Comment: *Tried n true™* with a few small sinatra 2.0 apps on my VPS. It works out of the box and let rack handle the webserver: i use (oh God i'm saying it publicly) *webrick* and the method above for any small app i deploy (capistrano).